# Unity 2D, control a simple shot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I have to control a shot of a ball with touch. All works fine but I need to start my trajectory when I touch the screen, but the trajectory start only when the ball is touched. Is because the script is attached to the ball?
All touch input except touches on the ball is ignored.

Here is the C# script , can someone help me?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;


namespace Shorka.BallTrajectory
{
    public enum PullState
    {
        Idle,
        UserPulling,
        ObjFlying
    }

    public class PullCtrl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region fields
        //[SerializeField] private Transform throwTarget;
        [SerializeField] private ThrownObject throwObj;

        [SerializeField] private Transform dotHelper;
        [SerializeField] private Transform pullingStartPoint;

        [Space(5)]
        [Tooltip("this linerenderer will draw the projected trajectory of the thrown object")]
        [SerializeField]
        private LineRenderer trajectoryLineRen;

        [SerializeField]
        private TrailMaker trail;

        [Space(5)]
        [SerializeField]
        private float throwSpeed = 10F;

        [Tooltip("Max Distance between 'PullingStartPoint' and pulling touch point")]
        [SerializeField]
        private float maxDistance = 1.5F;

        [SerializeField]
        private float coofDotHelper = 1.5F;

        [Tooltip("Related to length of trajectory line")]
        [SerializeField]
        private int qtyOfsegments = 13;

        [Tooltip("Step of changing trajectory dots offset in runtime")]
        [SerializeField]
        private float stepMatOffset = 0.01F;

        [Tooltip("Z position of trajectory dots")]
        [SerializeField]
        private float dotPosZ = 0F;

        private PullState pullState;
        private Camera camMain;
        //private Collider2D collThrowTarget;
        private Rigidbody2D rgThrowTarget;

        private Vector3 posPullingStart;
        private Vector3 initPos;

        private TrajectoryCtrl trajCtrl;
        #endregion

        public Vector3 PosDotHelper { get { return dotHelper.position; } }
        public Vector3 PosThrowTarget { get { return throwObj.transform.position; } }

        public int QtyOfsegments { get { return qtyOfsegments; } }
        public float DotPosZ { get { return dotPosZ; } }
        public Vector3 PosPullingStart { get { return posPullingStart; } }
        public float StepMatOffset { get { return stepMatOffset; } }



        void Awake()
        {
            trail.emit = false;
            trajCtrl = new TrajectoryCtrl(this, trajectoryLineRen);
        }

        void Start()
        {
            camMain = Camera.main;
            pullState = PullState.Idle;
            posPullingStart = pullingStartPoint.position;
            initPos = PosThrowTarget;

        }

        void Update()
        {
            SwitchStates();

        }

        private void SwitchStates()
        {
            switch (pullState)
            {
                case PullState.Idle:

                    if (Input.touchCount> 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                    {


                        Debug.Log("Screen touched");
                        //get the point on screen user has tapped
                        Vector3 location = camMain.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                        //if user has tapped onto the ball

                        if (throwObj.Collider == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(location))
                            pullState = PullState.UserPulling;
                    }
                    break;


                case PullState.UserPulling:

                    dotHelper.gameObject.SetActive(true);


                    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                    {


                        //get touch position
                        Vector3 touchPos = camMain.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                        touchPos.z = 0;
                        //we will let the user pull the ball up to a maximum distance
                        if (Vector3.Distance(touchPos, posPullingStart) > maxDistance)
                        {
                            Vector3 maxPosition = (touchPos - posPullingStart).normalized * maxDistance + posPullingStart;
                            maxPosition.z = dotHelper.position.z;
                            dotHelper.position = maxPosition;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            touchPos.z = dotHelper.position.z;
                            dotHelper.position = touchPos;
                        }

                        float distance = Vector3.Distance(posPullingStart, dotHelper.position);
                        trajCtrl.DisplayTrajectory(distance);
                    }
                    else if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Canceled || Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                    {
                        float distance = Vector3.Distance(posPullingStart, dotHelper.position);
                        trajectoryLineRen.enabled = false;
                        ThrowObj(distance);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }


        //private Vector2 velocityToRg = Vector2.zero;
        private void ThrowObj(float distance)
        {
            Debug.Log("ThrowObj");

            pullState = PullState.Idle;
            Vector3 velocity = posPullingStart - dotHelper.position;
            //velocityToRg = CalcVelocity(velocity, distance);

            throwObj.ThrowObj(CalcVelocity(velocity, distance));
            //rgThrowTarget.velocity = velocityToRg;
            //rgThrowTarget.isKinematic = false;

            trail.enabled = true;
            trail.emit = true;
            dotHelper.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }


        public void Restart(Vector3 posThrownObj)
        {
            trail.emit = false;
            trail.Clear();

            StartCoroutine(ClearTrail());

            trajectoryLineRen.enabled = false;
            dotHelper.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            pullState = PullState.Idle;

            throwObj.Reset(posThrownObj);
        }

        private readonly WaitForSeconds wtTimeBeforeClear = new WaitForSeconds(0.3F);
        IEnumerator ClearTrail()
        {
            yield return wtTimeBeforeClear;
            trail.Clear();
            trail.enabled = false;
        }

        Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
        public Vector3 CalcVelocity(Vector3 diff, float distance)
        {
            velocity.x = diff.x * throwSpeed * distance * coofDotHelper;
            velocity.y = diff.y * throwSpeed * distance * coofDotHelper;

            return velocity;
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easy. you need to add these two scripts to the gameobject (not the ball but the one which is used to shoot the ball something like a gun)

> TouchEventTrigger.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class TouchEventTrigger : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler,   IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler {
public TouchEvent onClick;
public TouchEvent onDown;
public TouchEvent onUp;

public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData e) {
    onClick.Invoke(e);
}

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData e) {
    onDown.Invoke(e);
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData e) {
    onUp.Invoke(e);
}
}

[System.Serializable]
public class TouchEvent : UnityEvent<PointerEventData> {}
```

> Shooter.cs

```
public void TryBeginAim(PointerEventData e) {
    if(canShoot) {
        initialTouchPos = e.position;
    }
}

public void TryAim(PointerEventData e) {
    if(canShoot) {
        direction = initialTouchPos - e.position;
        float mag = (initialTouchPos - e.position).magnitude;
        float scale = Mathf.Clamp(mag/maxMagnitude, scaleThreshold, 1f);
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y,direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + 90f; 

        aim.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);


        aim.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * scale;
        aim.SetActive(e.position.y < initialTouchPos.y);
    }
}

public void TryShoot(PointerEventData e) {
    if(canShoot && aim.activeInHierarchy) {
        canShoot = false;
        StartCoroutine(ShootRoutine(balls));
    }

    aim.SetActive(false);
}

private IEnumerator ShootRoutine(int b) {
    // write code to start shooting balls.
}
```

Then connect the touch events with the methods like this: 
1. OnPointerClick => TryBeginAim 
2. OnPointerDown => TryAim 
3. OnPointerUp => TryShoot

That's All !! 
I hope this helps to solve this issue. Enjoy!

Comment: Shah Thank you, I will try. But my past code remains  as well?

Comment: @Mtt95dvlpr for testing this code, remove portion of the code from your previous attempt which dealt with the touch event.